# "E: The package libc6-dev needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it" after upgrade

Tags: software-installation

Since upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10, while using Ubuntu Software, I get

```
E: The package libc6-dev needs to be reinstalled, 
   but I can't find an archive for it
```

What to do to solve this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you on?  What are you trying to install?  When did this start happening?  We need a ton more information to even begin to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10. 
This start happening right after I updated from 17.04 to 17.10

Comment: Have you tried doing `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev`?  Or are there more errors than just that one?

Comment: No, there is only one error. 
If I try to reinstall, then I get following :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done


E: The package libc6-dev needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Close voters. Answered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451939/cant-install-libc6-package provides an explanation of how to reinstall a specific version of libc6

Answer (score 1):

There are very few reasons why you might not be able to install [libc6-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) as it's available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

One possibility is that you thought you had upgraded to 17.10 but did not succeed in the attempt, and it's looking for a 17.04 version [which has moved.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release/91821#91821)

You can confirm your current version of Ubuntu with the commands  `lsb_release -a` and `grep Ubuntu /etc/issue` The version listed on the Description line of the former commands output should match the version you get from the latter command.

Since you say you get no other errors the other possibilities (network down, sever down) are unlikely, so I won't bother suggesting that you [connect to the internet and choose a different mirror.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579997/why-does-the-update-manager-say-check-your-internet-connection/998710)